# Why does Left Method Skip Code and Exit Sub VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

As shown in the output below, when I use the left function, instead of going to the next line when I press f8, it jumps to the end of the sub. Why is this and how can I fix this?[image][image]

Comment: This isn't going to be reproducible. What "output" is there and how is it "messed up"?

Comment: Unhandled error, perhaps? Add an `On Error…` statement.

Comment: Please do not post your code in image...  Just a guess - Does `wksSignoff` variable exist or do you mean `wksSignoff_p`? It's weird that you loop to `wksSignoff_p`'s last row but you are using Left function on a cell in `wksSignoff`